# AST Remove object with function from code insert function body to main function?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, babel-parser

I try with ast (babel/parser) delete object assigment from function and insert operation function back to main function.

```
function ht(jW, d, e, f, g) {
  d = {}; d.SnIKx = function (h, i) {
    return i ^ h;
  }, d.cgmgz = function (h, i) {
    return i ^ h;
  },d.CelmY = function (h, i) {
    return h ^ i;
  }, e = d;
  return f = this.h[e.SnIKx(e.cgmgz(this.h[this.g ^ 54.48][3], 108 + this.h[e.CelmY(54, this.g)][1].charCodeAt(this.h[54 ^ this.g][0]++) & 255.13), 46) ^ this.g], f;
}
```

this function have proxy function in object. anybody know how i can get with babel/parser

need get:

```
function ht(jW, d, e, f, g) {
   return f = this.h[this.h[this.g ^ 54.48][3] ^ 108 + this.h[54 ^ this.g][1].charCodeAt(this.h[54 ^ this.g][0]++) & 255.13 ^ 46 ^ this.g], f;
}
```

```
const parser = require("@babel/parser");
const traverse = require("@babel/traverse").default;
const generator = require("@babel/generator").default;

const code = `function ht(jW, d, e, f, g) {
  d = {}; d.SnIKx = function (h, i) {
    return i ^ h;
  }, d.cgmgz = function (h, i) {
    return i ^ h;
  },d.CelmY = function (h, i) {
    return h ^ i;
  }, e = d;
  return f = this.h[e.SnIKx(e.cgmgz(this.h[this.g ^ 54.48][3], 108 + this.h[e.CelmY(54, this.g)][1].charCodeAt(this.h[54 ^ this.g][0]++) & 255.13), 46) ^ this.g], f;
}`;

// Parse the code
const ast = parser.parse(code, {
  sourceType: "module",
});


traverse(ast, {
BinaryExpression(path) {
        if (path.node.left.type === 'CallExpression')
        {
            if (path.node.left.callee && path.node.left.callee.property)
            {
                console.log(path.node.left.callee.property) // Get SnIKx
                console.log(path.node.left.callee.object) // Get e
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: This is known as [function inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion).